# typescript import modules into one inline js

Tags: typescript, browser, import

I'm looking for a way to import multiple modules into output single file which will be run by a browser.

Something like:

```
import externalModule from 'external-module';

console.log(externalModule);
```

into

```
// var externalModule = content of the external module
console.log(externalModule);
```

is it possible to do with Typescript

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I ended up with making a bundle with Webpack.